# How to hide context click? Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How would I undo the context click in selenium to make it disappear?
For example, I right click (menu appears), then remove menu from screen..
I just want to remove the context menu.

```
// Right click menu
var content = driver.FindElement(By.Id("content")); 
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.ContextClick(content).Build().Perform();
// Now how do I remove the right click menu?
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try sending ESC in sendKeys method from action class?

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
```

Comment: doesn't seem to respond

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you normally use normal click action at any empty location on the page after it in order to make the context menu disappear?

Comment: Did you try click the same element again:
    act.ContextClick(content).Build().Perform();
    act.Click(content).Build().Perform();

Comment: Yup did that too :( still there

Comment: My last suggestion is to use a normal click action instead of using Actions class: driver.FindElement(By.Id("content")).click(). If it didn't work,the final option would be to just refresh driver.Navigate().Refresh(); Please try and let me know

Comment: What is the best way to find an empty location to click on? I have trouble on some pages where the empty elements have no Id, no unique class/css.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found when I got this issue.
It only happens in chrome.

Nothing works to get rid of the menu:

- clicking on another element on the page
- refreshing page
- navigating to a different page and then refreshing
- clicking Escape

And it looks like since it (menu) is open the driver cannot be closed so you get this:

**error**
*"WebDriver unknown error: failed to close window in 20 seconds"*

**Apparently in Chrome** it thinks that there are multiple windows when the right click (generic | browser) menu is shown.

**SOLUTION**: The solution was to switch from `driver.close()` to `driver.quit()`

So browser window will at least close.