# How to get out of a context click in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, right-click

This has been asked before here: [How to hide context click? Selenium Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016099/how-to-hide-context-click-selenium-chromedriver)

But none of the solutions there have worked for me. There is an element on my webpage that requires a right-click to select it (weird, but it makes sense with the site). I am able to click this element using

```
action.context_click(src).perform()
```

And I have tried to get rid of the menu that pops up after right-clicking 4 separate ways

```
# Left-clicking in the same spot after I have right-clicked
action.click().perform()

# Hitting the space bar
webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()

# Hitting the escape key
webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

# Clicking on an unused element
action.move_to_element(WebDriverWait (self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "html"))))
action.click().perform()

# Reloading the page did not get rid of it either
self.driver.refresh()
```

None of these methods have worked to get rid of the menu that pops up. I cannot reload the page to get rid of this otherwise it will deselect the object I am trying to get. This does not affect my program but it is annoying to have it in my way when I am trying to spectate what my program is doing. Any help is appreciated! This is something in my free time so it is not time-sensitive.

Comment: did you try clicking on some other element or some empty space?

Comment: I have not I will give that a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: @AbiSaran I tried clicking the main html element and still got no results. Updated my post with the line I added in to try and fix it

Comment: Did you try to hide the pop up by modifying its attrubute? For example `popup = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '...'); driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:none')", popup)`

Comment: @soundwave what would go in place of the ellipsis? the XPath of the context menu?

Comment: Yes the xpath of the webelement that you want to hide. If you prefer you can use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `By.ID` etc

Comment: @soundwave The element I want to hide is the actual "right-click" menu that pops up when I right-click (like the one that says "save page" "inspect" etc). I don't think there is an XPATH to that. If I'm wrong let me know!

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't get it, so try `pip install pyautogui` and then `import pyautogui; pyautogui.press('esc')`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to open the context menu (right click) on a random site and then I was able to close it with `pyautogui` (`pip install pyautogui`)

```
action.context_click(src).perform()

import pyautogui    
pyautogui.press('esc')
```

It may be possible that you have to press `esc` a couple of times.